# Game of Noughts and Crosses Feedback

Tags: python, game, tic-tac-toe

this is my 2nd project on Python. I created a game of Noughts and Crosses(Tic-Tac-Toe) that you can play against the computer. What are your thoughts on my implementation of the game? Is there anything I've missed or could improve upon?

I did think about adding a figure window and making it more interactive by clicking on where you want to move however that seemed a bit too advanced.

```
import random    
import sys
import numpy as np

# Today we are going to make an interactive game in Python.
# This is going to be a game of noughts and crosses!

#  Initialise grid and collection of X's or O's needed to win a game.
grid = [["_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_"]]
print(np.asarray(grid))  # To make the output represent a grid instead of a list of lists.
row_os = ["O", "O", "O"]
row_xs = ["X", "X", "X"]
coords_picked = []

# Create a loop to find all co-ordinates in our grid
all_coords = []
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        all_coords.append((x, y))

turn = 0
remaining_coords = []

while turn < 10:
    # Find status of each column
    column_1 = [row[0] for row in grid]
    column_2 = [row[1] for row in grid]
    column_3 = [row[2] for row in grid]

    # Find status of 2 diagonals
    main_diag = [row[i] for i, row in enumerate(grid)]
    counter_diag = [row[-i - 1] for i, row in enumerate(grid)]

    # Winning conditions for each player
    if (grid[0] == row_os or grid[1] == row_os or grid[2] == row_os) or (
        column_1 == row_os or column_2 == row_os or column_3 == row_os) or (main_diag == row_os) or (
        counter_diag == row_os):
        print("The computer has won!")
        sys.exit()
    elif (grid[0] == row_xs or grid[1] == row_xs or grid[2] == row_xs) or (
        column_1 == row_xs or column_2 == row_xs or column_3 == row_xs) or (main_diag == row_xs) or (
        counter_diag == row_xs):
        print("Well done, you have won!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        # If nobody has won yet, take another turn
        if turn % 2 == 0:
            x_coord = input()
            y_coord = input()
            coords_picked.append((int(x_coord), int(y_coord)))
            grid[int(x_coord)][int(y_coord)] = "X"
            print(np.asarray(grid))
            turn += 1
        else:
            # Computer randomly picks a co-ordinate in the grid that has not been picked yet
            remaining_coords = list(set(all_coords) - set(coords_picked))
            comp_coords = random.choice(remaining_coords)
            grid[comp_coords[0]][comp_coords[1]] = "O"
            coords_picked.append((comp_coords[0], comp_coords[1]))
            print(comp_coords)
            print(np.asarray(grid))
            turn += 1

print("A draw?! We must play again!")
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't use `numpy`, and I'm getting errors when trying to use it on 3.9, but it seems unnecessary here. If you want to pretty-print a grid, that can be done succinctly using `join`:

```
def format_grid(grid):
    return "\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in grid)
```

Which, when you replace all uses of `asarray`, gives output like:

```
X _ _
_ _ _
_ _ O
```

I wouldn't import `numpy` just to help format. That's a heavy dependency for little gain.

---

These lines:

```
grid = [["_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_"]]
row_os = ["O", "O", "O"]
row_xs = ["X", "X", "X"]
```

Can make use of "sequence multiplication" to reduce the duplication:

```
SIDE_LENGTH = 3    

grid = [["_"] * SIDE_LENGTH for _ in range(SIDE_LENGTH)]
row_os = ["O"] * SIDE_LENGTH 
row_xs = ["X"] * SIDE_LENGTH
```

---

I'd change `all_coords`, `coords_picked`, and `remaining_coords` to be sets from the start. It isn't efficient to create them as lists, then convert them to sets whenever you want to use them. This unfortunately requires that `remaining_coords` be converted to a list before being given to `random.choice`, but that's still less conversions being done overall.

You could probably just get rid of `remaining_coords` too and just use:

```
comp_coords = random.choice(list(all_coords - coords_picked))
```

You have it as a global variable, even though you're recalculating it each time anyways. It would be even more efficient though to not recalculate it each time, and instead make a copy of `all_coords` at the start, then `del` elements from the set as they're picked. That's probably an unnecessary level of optimization for here though.

---

You can clean up the winning checks by making use of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and comprehensions. First, change `column_1`, `column_2`, and `column_3` to:

```
columns = [[row[i]
           for row in grid]
           for i in range(SIDE_LENGTH)]
```

Whenever you're postfixing variable names with numbers, you probably want a list instead.

Next, the conditions themselves:

```
if any((any(row == row_os for row in grid),
        any(col == row_os for col in columns),
        any(diag == row_os for diag in [main_diag, counter_diag]))):
    print("The computer has won!")
    sys.exit()
elif any((any(row == row_xs for row in grid),
          any(col == row_xs for col in columns),
          any(diag == row_xs for diag in [main_diag, counter_diag]))):
    print("Well done, you have won!")
    sys.exit()
```

There's probably a better way of writing this still, but I haven't had my coffee yet. Basically, I'm again using a comprehensions (or rather, generator expressions) to reduce duplication. If you're writing `grid[0]`, `grid[1]`, `grid[2]` manually, you likely want to iterate over `grid` instead.

You could also wrap that condition up in a function, then use the function in both places since each condition is basically the same.

The inner `any`s could also be replaced with unpacking to make use of the outer `any`:

```
if any((*(row == row_os for row in grid),
        *(col == row_os for col in columns),
        *(diag == row_os for diag in [main_diag, counter_diag]))):
```

But I'm not sure that that's much better.

---

You should add in error handling. When testing this, I got multiple errors. I accidentally entered `3` in, and got an `IndexError`, and accidentally pressed enter without entering a number and got a `ValueError`. Really, the user entering bad input should be expected and handled.

---

---

At the end, I have:

```
import random
import sys

SIDE_LENGTH = 3


def format_grid(grid):
    return "\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in grid)


grid = [["_"] * SIDE_LENGTH for _ in range(SIDE_LENGTH)]
row_os = ["O"] * SIDE_LENGTH
row_xs = ["X"] * SIDE_LENGTH
coords_picked = set()

print(format_grid(grid))  # To make the output represent a grid instead of a list of lists.

# Create a loop to find all co-ordinates in our grid
all_coords = set()
for x in range(SIDE_LENGTH):
    for y in range(SIDE_LENGTH):
        all_coords.add((x, y))

turn = 0
remaining_coords = set()

while turn < 10:
    # Find status of each column
    columns = [[row[i]
               for row in grid]
               for i in range(SIDE_LENGTH)]

    # Find status of 2 diagonals
    main_diag = [row[i] for i, row in enumerate(grid)]
    counter_diag = [row[-i - 1] for i, row in enumerate(grid)]

    # Winning conditions for each player
    if any((any(row == row_os for row in grid),
            any(col == row_os for col in columns),
            any(diag == row_os for diag in [main_diag, counter_diag]))):
        print("The computer has won!")
        sys.exit()
    elif any((any(row == row_xs for row in grid),
            any(col == row_xs for col in columns),
            any(diag == row_xs for diag in [main_diag, counter_diag]))):
        print("Well done, you have won!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        # If nobody has won yet, take another turn
        if turn % 2 == 0:
            x_coord = input()
            y_coord = input()
            coords_picked.add((int(x_coord), int(y_coord)))
            grid[int(x_coord)][int(y_coord)] = "X"
            print(format_grid(grid))
            turn += 1
        else:
            # Computer randomly picks a co-ordinate in the grid that has not been picked yet
            remaining_coords = all_coords - coords_picked
            comp_coords = random.choice(list(remaining_coords))
            grid[comp_coords[0]][comp_coords[1]] = "O"
            coords_picked.add((comp_coords[0], comp_coords[1]))
            print(comp_coords)
            print(format_grid(grid))
            turn += 1

print("A draw?! We must play again!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and help, I'll make sure to add the corrections and exceptions!